# Publish PointCloud descriptors

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to publish my calculated point cloud descriptors like so

```
pub_descriptors = nh.advertise<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::SHOT352>::Ptr> ("descriptors", 1);
```

but ROS won't let me because it cannot serialize it throwing a really long error. What is the prettiest way of solving this problem? What is the fastest one? In the end I do not always want to publish SHOT352 descriptors but also try FPFH and some others. Do I need to create a new message type for any descriptor I want to try out? Is there a way to have that work similar to image_transport where I can subscribe to all available compressions?

Kai

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56145/publish-pointcloud-descriptors/) by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1554 on 2013-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have correctly identified that you cannot publish a datatype without serialization defined.

To enable serialization you need to have an isomorphic data type. So if you're trying different descriptors you will likely need to create new isomorphic ros messages to represent the data.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0